# Simple javascript calculation

Tags: javascript, html, sharepoint-2010

Its been many years that I've had to do anything with javascript. Feel like I need to take a course just to relearn the basics. Trying to create a simple calculation with two input fields. Found the following solution on another post but it is not working for me.

```js
<script>
  function calculate() {
      var myBox1 = document.getElementById('box1').value;   
      var myBox2 = document.getElementById('box2').value;
      var result = document.getElementById('result');   
      var myResult = myBox1 * myBox2;
      result.value = myResult;
      
      
   }
</script>
```

```html
<table width="250px" border="0">
  <tr>
    <th>Box 1</th>
    <th></th>
    <th>Box 2</th>
    <th></th>
    <th>Result</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><input id="box1" type="text" oninput="calculate()" /></td>
    <td>x</td>
    <td><input id="box2" type="text" oninput="calculate()" /></td>
 <td>=</td>
    <td><input id="result" /></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Eventually I will have default values for the two input field and allow the user to change the values and see how the result changes. PLanning to use on a SharePoint 2010 intranet site.

I feel like whatever I am getting wrong is a very simple thing that I am overlooking.

Thanks

Comment: Remove the `<script>` tags from your example, and it works!

Comment: [It works fine here](http://jsfiddle.net/m37j9ftw/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the code above is working fine. If you want to have some default values just set the fields values on page load. You can do it by doing: `window.onload = function (){....}` or width jQuery `$(document).ready(function(){....}`

Here is an example with your code plus added default values for your fields:
http://codepen.io/anon/pen/PwExrw

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion on the default values. If the script is working for you I think there may be some issues with the browsers in our office. Because of compatability issues with internal applications all our browsers are IE 7 or 8 :(

Comment: compared my script to yours and changing oninput="calculate()" to onkeyup="calculate()" fixed the problem. 

Thanks

Comment: Ah.. sorry man, after I saw it I just changed it and totally forgot that onkeyup wasn't in your code :)